# Is it possible to increment a variable used in ForEach SWIFTUI

Tags: swiftui

```
ForEach(questionsManager.answerChoices, id:\.id) { answer in
     AnswerRow(index: i, answer: answer).environmentObject(questionsManager)
}
```

"i" is a @State variable in my View Struct that is assigned to zero

I want the index of each AnswerRow to be set from 0 to 3, how to manage that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than the elements iterate the `indices` of the array

```
ForEach(questionsManager.answerChoices.indices, id: \.self) { i in
     AnswerRow(index: i, answer: questionsManager.answerChoices[i]).environmentObject(questionsManager)
}
```

The `@State` variable is actually not needed.

Side note: As you pass the `questionsManager` in the environment the `answer` parameter is not needed either.

Comment: Acessing an array by index inside a `ForEach` View's closure will crash if the array changes, you have to learn how `ForEach` works with `Identifiable` data, it's not a for loop.

Comment: @malhal If the array changes the indices change and the view will be redrawn. And consecutive indices are unique aka identifiable.

Comment: you're missing one thing, the closure captures the old version of the array so it'll crash with index out of range if an item was deleted. When the array changes, the closure can be called before body has been updated. This is why ForEach is designed to work with IDs not indices.

Comment: It doesn't seem – in this particular case – that the choices are going to be deleted. But as I mentioned in the answer, if the manager is being passed in the environment both the index and the element is not needed.